# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. lambda_method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My project was working well but now it gives me this error.

[image]

The controller is `HomeController`

```
public IActionResult Index(int page=1)
{
    IPagedList<ProductTbl> productList = _context.ProductTbl.OrderByDescending(e => e.Id).ToPagedList<ProductTbl>(25, page); //using pagination
    return View(productList);
}
```

Similarly, I'm getting the same error in the following code.

```
 List<ProductTbl> products = _context.ProductTbl.ToList();
```

But, I'm not getting the error in the following line of code.

```
List<CityTbl> cities = _context.CityTbl.ToList();
```

Both lines of code are in the same controller action method.

That's my DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext  
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<ProductTbl> ProductTbl { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CityTbl> CityTbl { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `_context.ProductTbl.OrderByDescending(e => e.Id).ToPagedList(25, page);`

Also I might be wrong but it looks like you have the parameters for the pagedList conversion the wrong way round, it should look like `.ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);` so in your case it would be `.ToPagedList(page, 25);`

Also I would recommend reading the documentation on the error you get at [InvalidCastException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I found this helpful. I had internet failure. Bro, as i explained above why this happening that tolist() is working for one dataset like CityTbl but not for ProductTbl

Comment: Do you get any errors?. I'm not sure about your question, are you saying `ToList()` isnt coming up when you try to use it?

Comment: No, `ToList()` work when i use it with my `CityTbl` dataset but gives and 'InvalidCasteExcetption' when i use it with `ProductTbl`. Yes, it's happening. I added new migratios and updated my database but again that's happening. I have added a screen shot for more elaboration.

Comment: what does your product table look like in your context?

Comment: I couldn't understand

Comment: the class that references `_context` what does it look like

Comment: What does your ProductTbl took like?